# Trouble in creating pods in git bash terminal

Tags: kubernetes

I'm unable to create a pod in gitbash terminal.

I have created a yaml file in Visual editor but when i did cat command it is showing no such file or directory
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hot0X.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you save the file after editing? This seems more like a bash issue than a Kubernetes issue.

You can run the `id` command to see the user you're running as. Then use `ls -l` to see that the user has write permissions to your current directory.

Comment: hey ty and yes I didnt save the file actually, i got it.

Comment: Great! Perhaps consider upvoting the answer and accepting it :)